# Pulling dataframes from multiple URLs, exporting to one CSV

Tags: python-3.x

I'm relatively new to Python and coding in general, and am struggling with a project I'm working on.

I'm trying to pull data from multiple URLs into one large spreadsheet. I think the dataframe is being overwritten in the loop, but I'm not sure how to instead pull them all together and into one large spreadsheet.

Advice would be appreciated!
*Updated*

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

dates = ['Jan2014', 'Feb2014', 'Mar2014', 'Apr2014', 'May2014', 'Jun2014', 'Jul2014', 'Aug2014', 'Sep2014', 'Oct2014', 'Nov2014', 'Dec2014']
urlprefix = 'https://www.testurl.com'

for i in dates:
    page = urlprefix + i + 'expenses.htm'

    html = requests.get(page).content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    df = df_list[-1]
    df_list.append(df)

big_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
print(big_df)
big_df.to_csv('render.csv', encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

Answer (score 1):

- [`.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) can read tables directly

  - *Read HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects.*
- Your current code gets a list of dataframes, takes the last dataframe in the list and then appends it to the same list.

```py
import pandas as pd

dates = ['Jan2014', 'Feb2014', 'Mar2014', 'Apr2014', 'May2014', 'Jun2014', 'Jul2014', 'Aug2014', 'Sep2014', 'Oct2014', 'Nov2014', 'Dec2014']
urlprefix = 'https://www.testurl.com'

df_list = list()  # list of dataframes to keep

for i in dates:
    page = urlprefix + i + 'expenses.htm'

    df = pd.read_html(page)[-1]  # get dataframe of last table
    df_list.append(df)  # append to list of dataframes to keep


big_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
print(big_df)
big_df.to_csv('render.csv', encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer and the detailed comment. This is super helpful. Really appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

add a variable `df_list`, and in the loop do `df_list.append(df)`

Then when out of the loop do `big_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Thanks, but the last URL in the loop is now just downloading twice and exporting to a CSV?

Comment: @r0gerr0ger Because you are resetting `df_list` in the body of the loop. Notice that nowhere in my answer do I suggest you do that. remove the line after `html=...`and ADD `df_list = []` before the loop.